# Is this a bug? Or does the anonymous users workflow occur differently?

Tags: ios, parse-server

**Issue Description**

I am using the latest version of parse-server and the latest iOS SDK to create a simple sign up flow involving anonymous users. What happens is the user gets the following error when attempting to log out:

> invalid session token (Code: 209, Version: 1.13.0)

**Steps to reproduce**

My app launches and the following code executes in my AppDelegate.swift file.

```
let parseConfig = ParseClientConfiguration {
        $0.applicationId = "insertAppIdHere"
        $0.clientKey = "insertClientKeyHere"
        $0.server = "https://MyParseServer.com/parse"
    }
    Parse.initializeWithConfiguration(parseConfig)

    PFUser.enableAutomaticUser()
    PFUser.currentUser()!.saveInBackground()
```

There are no issues that appear to occur.

Now I Sign Up the user to convert their account from anonymous status to normal (non-anonymous) status using the signUp function in the iOS SDK. This occurs after filling in a number of fields and tapping a 'sign up' button.

```
        let user = PFUser.currentUser()!
        user.username = self.emailTextField.text
        user.password = self.passwordTextField.text
        user.email = self.emailTextField.text
        user.signUpInBackgroundWithBlock({ (succeed, error) -> Void in
            if (error == nil) {
                self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
            } else {
                print(error!.description)
            }
        })
```

At this point there appears to be no session token on the server. This is a problem.

And so now I tap a button to log out.

```
PFUser.logOutInBackgroundWithBlock({(error) -> Void in
            if (error == nil) {
                logOutBarButton.enabled = true
                self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
            } else {
                logOutBarButton.enabled = true
                let errorVC = UIAlertController(title: "Oops..", message: "You Cannot Log Out at the Moment.", preferredStyle: .Alert)
                errorVC.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default, handler: { action in }))
                self.presentViewController(errorVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }

        })
```

and get the error (as expected) in the console: invalid session token (Code: 209, Version: 1.13.0)

**Expected Results**

I shouldn't see an error, there should be a valid session token after sign up on the server.

**Actual Outcome**

invalid session token (Code: 209, Version: 1.13.0)
Environment Setup

**Server**
        parse-server version: 2.2.15
        Hosted on: Google App Engine

**Database**
        MongoDB version: 3.0.12
        Hosted on: mLab

**Additional Notes**

Note that every time I did this test I made sure the database was empty. That also means I am not migrating anything from the original parse.

Logging out a second time succeeds, but I think this is because it just locally sets the currentUser to nil.

The whole thing could be a misunderstanding of how anonymous users work (further clarification would be helpful). I am almost certain though that this could have worked on original parse, since I have seen similar implementations in repositories on github. Example: (https://github.com/appflock/open/blob/master/ios/Reveal/AppDelegate.m)

How can I stop this error from occurring while using anonymous users on parse-server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will be hopefully be fixed with the upcoming 2.2.17